# Generate random date of a particular month in order using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, python-datetime

How to Generate random date of a particular month in this particular format.in order wise i.e., from 1 of month to 30 of that month

`2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z`

Tried this but it generates in regular time date format. This code generates randomly but i need the values in order from 1 to 30/31 of that month

```
from datetime import datetime

d1 = datetime.strptime('1/1/2010 1:30 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')
d2 = datetime.strptime('1/1/2011 4:50 AM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')

print(random_date(d1, d2))
```

Comment: How many values do you need?

Comment: from 1st of that month to 30th of that month

Comment: Then where does the "random" part of your question come in if you need a date from 1 to the end of the month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can get the difference in seconds between your datetimes then use [random.randrange](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange)

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import random

def random_date(d1, d2):
    delta = d2 - d1
    seconds = delta.total_seconds()
    n = random.randrange(seconds)
    return d1 + timedelta(seconds=n)

d1 = datetime.strptime('1/1/2010 1:30 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')
d2 = datetime.strptime('1/1/2011 4:50 AM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')

print(random_date(d1, d2).isoformat(timespec='milliseconds')+'Z')
```

Comment: "Need in this format 2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z" - then you should use the [strftime method of the datetime instance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime)

Comment: Or just call the [isoformat method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat) as in my edited answer

Comment: format is right, but i need the values in order from 1 to 30/31 of that month